# Javascript regex parsing dots and whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript I have several words separated by either a dot or one ore more whitepaces (or the end of the string).
I'd like to replace certain parts of it to insert custom information at the appropriate places.

Example:

```
var x = "test1.test     test2 test3.xyz test4";
```

If there's a dot it should be replaced with ".X_"
If there's one or more space(s) and the word before does not contain a dot, replace with ".X "

So the desired output for the above example would be:

```
"test1.X_test test2.X test3.X_xyz test4.X"
```

Can I do this in one regex replace? If so, how?
If I need two or more what would they be?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Your rules will not produce the desired output

Comment: Don't you mean, if there's not a dot in the word, it should append `.X` at the end of this word?

Comment: @WillP.: I corrected the rules.
rednaw: you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = 'test1.test     test2 test3.xyz test4';

str = str.replace(/(\w+)\.(\w+)/g, '$1.X_$2');
str = str.replace(/( |^)(\w+)( |$)/g, '$1$2.X$3');

console.log(str);
```

In the first `replace` it replaces the dot in the dotted words with a `.X_`, where a dotted word is *two words with a dot between them*.

In the second `replace` it adds `.X` to words that have no dot, where *words that have no dot* are words that are preceded by *a space* OR *the start of the string* and are followed by *a space* OR *the end of the string*.

Comment: That's perfect! exactly what I needed!
There's a little error though: The third parameter "str" is not needed. :)
**Thanks a lot though!**

Comment: @JanPaepke Yeah you're right, I made this in python first so that was a copy/paste error. I edited myself now because for some reason your edit got rejected by other people.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this:

> If there's a dot it should be replaced with ".X_"
>
> If there's one or more spaces it should be replaced with ".X"

Do this:

```
x.replace(/\./g, '.X_').replace(/\s+/g, '.X');
```

**Edit:** To get your desired output (rather than your rules), you can do this:

```
var words = x.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ');
for (var i = 0, l = words.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (words[i].indexOf('.') === -1) {
        words[i] += ".X";
    }
    else {
        words[i] = words[i].replace(/\./g, '.X_');
    }
}
x = words.join(' ');
```

Basically...

1. Strip all multiple spaces and create an array of "words"
2. Loop through each word.
3. If it doesn't have a period in it, then add ".X" to the end of the word
4. Else, replace the periods with ".X_"
5. Join the "words" back into a string and separate it by spaces.

**Edit 2**:

Here's a solution using only javascript's replace function:

```
x.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')  // replace multiple spaces with one space
 .replace(/\./g, '.X_') // replace dots with .X_
 // find words without dots and add a ".X" to the end
 .replace(/(^|\s)([^\s\.]+)($|\s)/g, "$1$2.X$3");
```

Comment: thanks. That's close, but not quite it. With this regex it would also add an .X after a "x.X_y". So in above example the first part would be "test1.X_test.X", which is wrong...

Comment: Thanks - the loop was kind of my fall back. I am looking for a more elegant way of doing it.
There should be a regex for "match spaces, but only if there is no dot between it and the last space"

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution using only the replace function.